# keep directory but delete files in it with dropbox bash api

Tags: bash, dropbox

`wp-dropbox` is a directory in my dropbox.

```
Dropbox-Uploader/dropbox_uploader.sh delete  /wp-dropbox
```

The command delete the `wp-dropbox` and all files in it.
How can i keep the directory --`wp-dropbox`,at the same time to delete all files in it?

```
Dropbox-Uploader/dropbox_uploader.sh delete  /wp-dropbox/*
```

The above command can't achieve my target.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Dropbox API doesn't offer the ability to delete all of the files in a folder without deleting the folder itself. We'll consider it a feature request.

Workarounds:

- List all of the files and delete them specifically.
- Delete the folder entirely, and then recreate just the folder.